# Invalid Column Name errors in dynamic query. Works in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I'm in the middle of going from SQL Server 2008 (not R2) to SQL Server 2012. I've restored my database into SQL Server 2012 but I'm getting runtime errors trying to call a certain dynamic query.

When I call this query from ASP, I'm getting a 500 error, and in the logs it says that I have an

> Invalid column name 'Vendor'.

When I run the same procedure directly in SSMS it tells me I have the following errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
>   Invalid column name 'Vendor'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
>   Invalid column name 'Type'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
>   Invalid column name 'SubType'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
>   Invalid column name 'CustPrice'.

Here's the code in the stored procedure. The problem is only occurring when `@mode = 'Search'`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProductSearch]
                @idCompany      int = 0,
                @idBusiness     int = 0,
                @cat            int = 0,
                @subCat         int = 0,
                @idPerson       int = 0,
                @target         nvarchar(99),
                @targetSQL      nvarchar(99),
                @priceLower     money = 0,
                @priceUpper     money = 999999999.99,
                @orderBy        nvarchar(9),
                @grouping       int = 1,
                @inStock        int = 0,
                @isCurrent      int = 0,
                @mode           nvarchar(99)

AS 
Set nocount on

DECLARE         @sql            nvarchar(4000),                                
                @paramlist      nvarchar(4000),
                @orderLit       varchar(99),
                @margin         decimal(9,5)


Select  @margin = margin 
From    Company 
Where   idCompany = @idCompany              

-- Determine the Select Statement

If @mode = 'Consumables'
Begin
    Select @sql = 
        'Select *
            FROM        dbo.PrinterConsumable pc 
            INNER JOIN  dbo.vwProductListAll p 
            ON          pc.consumableID = p.ProductID 
            WHERE       p.idCompany = @idCompany 
            AND         pc.printerID = @target
            AND         p.CustPrice BETWEEN @priceLower AND @priceUpper'
End

If @mode = 'Drill'
Begin
    -- If drilling down through the Desktop subcat, show unique skus for vendorProductID and Supplier
    If @subcat = '1000010'
        Begin
            Select @sql = 
                'Select *
                    FROM        dbo.vwProductListAll P      
                    INNER JOIN
                        (SELECT      vendorProductID, idSupplier, MIN(dealerBuy) AS minDealerBuy
                        FROM           dbo.Product
                        GROUP BY vendorProductID, idSupplier) PS 
                        ON PS.vendorProductID = P.ProductID AND PS.idSupplier = P.idSupplier AND PS.minDealerBuy = P.DealerPrice
                        WHERE       p.idCompany = @idCompany 
                        AND         p.CustPrice BETWEEN @priceLower AND @priceUpper'
        End
    Else
        Begin
            Select @sql = 
                'Select *
                    FROM        dbo.vwProductListAll P      
                    WHERE       p.idCompany = @idCompany 
                    AND         p.CustPrice BETWEEN @priceLower AND @priceUpper'
        End
End

If @mode = 'Favs'
Begin
    Select @sql = 
        'Select *
            FROM        dbo.vwProductListAll p
            INNER JOIN  dbo.ProductFavs pf ON p.idProduct = pf.idProduct
            WHERE       p.idCompany = @idCompany 
            AND         pf.idPerson = @idPerson
            AND         p.CustPrice BETWEEN @priceLower AND @priceUpper'
End

If @mode = 'Search'
Begin
    Select @sql = 
            'SELECT B.businessName                                              As Vendor, 
                PC.cat                                                          As Type, 
                PSC.subCat                                                      As SubType,   
                P.idProduct,
                P.vendorProductID                                               As ProductID, 
                P.description                                                   As ProductDesc, 
                100 * dbo.fnCalcMargin(P.margin, PSC.margin, PC.margin, @margin) As Margin,
                ROUND(CAST(P.dealerBuy + P.dealerBuy * dbo.fnCalcMargin(P.margin, PSC.margin, PC.margin, @margin) AS money), 2) AS CustPrice, 
                CAST(P.rrp - (P.dealerBuy + P.dealerBuy * dbo.fnCalcMargin(P.margin, PSC.margin, PC.margin, @margin)) AS money) AS Saving,
                P.dealerBuy                                                     AS DealerPrice, 
                P.rrp,
                B.idBusiness,
                PC.idCat,
                PSC.idSubCat,
                Case IsNull(P.url, '''')
                When '''' Then 0 Else 1 End as hasLink, 
                Case IsNull(P.imgURL, '''')                 
                When '''' Then 0 Else 1 End as hasImage, 
                Case IsNull(PI.productInfo, '''')
                When '''' Then 0 Else 1 End as hasInfo, 
                Case IsNull(PI.overview, '''')
                When '''' Then 0 Else 1 End as hasOverView, 
                Case IsNull(PI.keyFeatures, '''')
                When '''' Then 0 Else 1 End as hasKeyFeatures, 
                Case IsNull(PI.warrantyInfo, '''')
                When '''' Then 0 Else 1 End as hasWty, 
                P.idSupplier, S.supplierName, S.location, P.inStock, p.due, p.isCurrent,
                P.imgURL, P.imgURL2, P.url, P.pdfLink, P.isBulkFreight, P.isDoubleFreight, P.isImported
            FROM            dbo.Business B      
            INNER JOIN      dbo.Product P           ON B.idBusiness = P.idBusiness
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductInfo PI      ON P.idProduct = PI.idProduct
            INNER JOIN      dbo.Supplier S          ON P.idSupplier = S.idSupplier
            INNER JOIN      dbo.ProductSubCat PSC   ON P.idSubCat = PSC.idSubCat
            INNER JOIN      dbo.ProductCat PC       ON PSC.idCat = PC.idCat
            WHERE           P.idCompany = @idCompany 
            AND             (ROUND(CAST(P.dealerBuy + P.dealerBuy * dbo.fnCalcMargin(P.margin, PSC.margin, PC.margin, @margin) AS money), 2) BETWEEN @priceLower AND @priceUpper)   
            AND             ((p.idProduct = @target) OR (P.vendorProductID = @target) OR (CONTAINS(p.description, @targetSQL)))' 
End

-- Determine Filter
If @mode = 'Drill'
Begin
    If @idBusiness > 0  
        Select @sql = @sql + '  AND idBusiness = @idBusiness '

    If @cat > 0  
        Select @sql = @sql + '  AND idCat = @cat '

    If @subCat > 0  
        Select @sql = @sql + '  AND idSubCat = @subCat '
End

If @inStock = 1
    Select @sql = @sql + ' AND p.instock > 0'

If @isCurrent = 1
    Select @sql = @sql + ' AND p.isCurrent = 1'

-- Determine Sorting
If @orderBy = 'Desc'
    Select @orderLit = 'p.ProductDesc'
Else if @orderBy = 'Price'  
    Select @orderLit = 'p.CustPrice'
Else
    Select @orderLit = 'p.ProductID'

-- Determine Grouping
If @grouping = 1
    Select @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY p.Vendor, p.Type, p.SubType, ' + @orderLit
Else
    Select @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY ' + @orderLit

-- Recompile hint to see if it resolves the query timeout issue.  It didn't!
-- Select @sql = @sql + ' OPTION (RECOMPILE);'

-- Setup the Parameter List 
Select @paramList = '@idCompany     int,
                     @idBusiness    int,
                     @cat           int,
                     @subCat        int,
                     @target        nvarchar(99),   
                     @targetSQL     nvarchar(99),
                     @priceLower    money,
                     @priceUpper    money = 999999999.99,
                     @margin        decimal(9,5),
                     @idPerson      int'    

-- Execute the query
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist, @idCompany, @idBusiness, @cat, @subCat, @target, @targetSQL, @priceLower, @priceUpper, @margin, @idPerson

IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    RETURN (1)  

 --return success code (0)
RETURN (0)
```

Not sure if this is relevant or not, but this code was originally written in SQL Server 2000. It's working okay in my SQL Server 2008 instance. I changed the compatibility level of the DB from 80 to 100 when I imported it into 2012.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the Order By part of the query.

```
-- Determine Sorting
If @orderBy = 'Desc'
    Select @orderLit = 'p.ProductDesc'
Else if @orderBy = 'Price'  
    Select @orderLit = 'p.CustPrice'
Else
    Select @orderLit = 'p.ProductID'

-- Determine Grouping
If @grouping = 1
    Select @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY p.Vendor, p.Type, p.SubType, ' + @orderLit
Else
    Select @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY ' + @orderLit
```

I removed the P. from infront of the derived column names and the query ran fine, ie:

```
-- Determine Sorting
If @orderBy = 'Desc'
    Select @orderLit = 'ProductDesc'
Else if @orderBy = 'Price'  
    Select @orderLit = 'CustPrice'
Else
    Select @orderLit = 'ProductID'

-- Determine Grouping
If @grouping = 1
    Select @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY Vendor, Type, SubType, ' + @orderLit
Else
    Select @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY ' + @orderLit
```

Funny how it was working okay in SQL2000 - 2008.